# Is there a way to get Traffic Source information from GA cookies?

Tags: php

there's a need to import "sources" data (Source, Medium, Campaign, etc.) into a CRM system. The problem is… I can't see any sources in the whole `$_REQUEST` variable. All I see is something like this:

```
{
  "form_param1": "value1",
  "form_param2": "value2",
  // ...
  "_ga": "GA1.3.1600000003.1500000021",
  "_gid": "GA1.3.1700000030.1500000021",
  "_ym_uid": "1522299222214669259",
  "_ym_isad": "2",
  "PHPSESSID": "7aXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX6d",
  "tmr_detect": "0|15XXXXXXXX76",
  "_ym_visorc_3XXXXXX0": "w"
}
```

Do I have *anything* here that can be used to extract data such as "Source", "Medium", "Campaign", etc.?

Comment: you can't using the cookie... GA cookies store ids that Google specific, if you need to import and store them you need to use Google Analytics API https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/

Comment: As a general rule, the content of a cookie is relevant only to the application that generated that cookie.

Comment: I understand, but there are services, capable of extracting "Trafic source" info from the visits and sending it to customer's CRM. I just don't get it where they take this info — it's not in the URL, it's not in the cookies; I think I've looked into Local Storage as well… :/